# Passing variables between codes snippet in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a simple CRUD app, now i need to grab a variable's value in a different `@{}` tag into my view, such as passing it as reference.

For example:

```
<!-- some html code-->
@{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;  
 }
<!-- other html code-->
@{
   int sum = a + b;
 }
```

Is it possible?

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example in View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    string your_variable ="value";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
bool check = true;
 }
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>



      @{

           int num1 = 10, num2 = 20;
      }

something here.....

      @{
           int num3 = num1 + num2;

       }

    The sum of @num1 and @num2 is @num3
     @your_variable  is @check
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see that I declared block using @ and inside this block I have declared razor variable and perform some calculation. After that closing the block I used these variables.

Comment: I saw that you perform this operations while the 2 block of code are into the `<body>`, but is it the same if one block is into the `<body>` and another is out of it?

Comment: @LeonardoBassi I updated my answer. Variable can be anyplace in view.